# How to make a crafting recipe for a custom spawn egg in minecraft bedrock edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to make a recipe for a custom entities spawn egg in Minecraft bedrock edition. I tried to use the give command, but I couldn't figure that out. I am not sure if it is possible, but does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible on vanilla Minecraft Bedrock. Use a behaviour pack, or a plugin if you’re on a PocketMine-MP Server.

Comment: I said custom entity which means I am using a behavior pack

Answer (score -2):

### You can make Shaped and Shapeless recipes:

In your addon's behavior folder, create another folder called "recipes". There you can add all your item's recipes in .json files (ex: spawn_egg.json). You can put one of the following codes in the file, editing it for your item:

1. *Shaped recipe* means the player has to put the ingredients in a certain pattern to produce the result: (example using the recipe for an acacia boat)

```
     { 
       "format_version": "1.12", 
       "minecraft:recipe_shaped": {
           "description": {  
               "identifier": "minecraft:acacia_boat" 
           }, 
           "tags": [
               "crafting_table" 
           ], 
           "groups": [ 
               "planks" 
           ], 
           "pattern": [
                    "#P#",
                    "###"
           ],   
           "key": {         
               "P": {           
                   "item": "minecraft:wooden_shovel"        
               },       
               "#": {           
                   "item": "minecraft:planks",          
                   "data": 4            
               }        
           },
           "result": {      
               "item": "minecraft:boat",        
               "data": 4        
           }    
       } 
     }
```

2. *Shapeless recipe* means that the player can put the ingredients in any order in the crafting table to produce the result. Just list the ingredients and how many ('count') of each ingredient. The ingredients can be any item in vanilla minecraft (ex: minecraft:apple) or any custom item that you make:

```
   {
      "format_version": "1.12",
      "minecraft:recipe_shapeless": {
          "description": {
              "identifier": "yourname:youritem"
          },
          "priority": 0,
          "ingredients": [
              {
                  "item": "name:firstingredient",
                  "data": 0,
                  "count": 2
              },
              {
                  "item": "name:secondingredient",
                  "data": 0,
                  "count": 1
              }

          ],
          "result": {
              "item": "yourname:youritem",
              "data": 0
          }
        }
    }
```

**Note:** You have to have "Experimental Gameplay" (in your minecraft world's settings) set to "ON" for your addon to work.

**I got the code from** [guide.bedrock.dev](https://guide.bedrock.dev/-/loot_tables-recipes-spawn_rules#h.mmztodujps1c).

Comment: Does this require an add-on to get started, or can you just create recipe jsons in Bedrock? If it's the first one, it would probably be helpful to include that in your answer as well.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my answer. (I don't know if it's possible to edit minecraft's original code, but addons can override it instead.)