# Can I make custom recipes without an addon?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

> Related to [How to make a crafting recipe for a custom spawn egg in minecraft bedrock edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374788/how-to-make-a-crafting-recipe-for-a-custom-spawn-egg-in-minecraft-bedrock-editio).

So I have heard about [knowledge books](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Knowledge_Book) in Minecraft and it can be used to make custom crafting recipes, and it isn't surprising considering it is shown in the Java inventory GUI. Since I play on Bedrock, I can't get these special books. I said before that I'm a programmer, but I can't get the in-game code and access the scripts of it with my phone.

So without coding (not commands), how can I make custom crafting recipes?

Comment: So JSON isn't a programming language, but by "no coding" are you including JSON or just JavaScript?

Comment: @Penguin Well, all programming languages are considered to be "not used for modifying" in this sense of the question.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand, are you counting JSON yes or no?

Comment: @Penguin Now that I understood about the JSON components, I guess you can use JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to create custom recipes via behavior packs. Examples of this are the "Bedrock Tweaks" crafting tweak packs. You can download some via the below link and open them with a zip program to view examples. I know that you can load these on mobile on Android for certain, and am under the impression it works for iOS as well.

http://bedrocktweaks.net/crafting-tweaks/

Note that loading custom behavior packs disables achievements for a world.